# User's permissions in feathers.js API

Tags: javascript, rest, permissions, feathersjs, feathers-authentication

I'm trying to create some REST API with user roles like admin, superadmin etc.
I was trying to achieve this by using `feathers-permissions` module, but there are none working examples and the internet. Have you ever dealt with such task?
What I do now is:
`feathers generate app` and then `feathers generate authentication`. What should I do next?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The secret to implementing permissions and roles in Feathers is that [Hooks](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/hooks.html) really provide everything you need with all the flexibility you might want. There isn't really a a need to spend time looking for a separate module and learning it's API.

Store the permissions (which are normally just strings) in an array on the user (or a separate `permissions` service based on the users ID) and then in a `before` hook check if the user is allowed to perform the operation the hook is registered as (here the permission is called `messages::create`), and if not throw a [Feathers error](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/errors.html):

```
const { Forbidden } = require('feathers-errors');

app.service('messages').hooks({
  before: {
    create: [ context => {
      // `params.provider` is set for any external access
      // usually we don't need to check permissions for internal calls
      const isExternal = !!context.params.provider;

      if(isExternal && !context.params.user.permissions.includes('messages::create')) {
        throw new Forbidden('You are not allowed to access this');
      }
    }]
  }
});
```

This pattern can also be implemented with any existing permissions module for Node. [feathers-permissions](https://github.com/feathersjs-ecosystem/feathers-permissions/) is a simple module that allows to do this more easily.

For more information also see the blog posts about [Access Control Strategies in FeathersJS](https://blog.feathersjs.com/access-control-strategies-with-feathersjs-72452268739d) and [Easy API Authorization with CASL and Feathers](https://blog.feathersjs.com/authorization-with-casl-in-feathersjs-app-fd6e24eefbff).